# How to ignore nonword charcters in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, regex, methods

I need to create a method called palindrome?

The palindrome?(string) must determine whether a given string (word or phrase) is a palindrome, that is, it reads the same backwards as forwards, ignoring case, punctuation, and nonword characters.

I can't understand what method to use to ignore nonword characters

```
def palindrome?(str)
  if str.reverse.downcase.delete(" ") == str.downcase.delete(" ")
    return true
  else 
    return false
  end
end
```

I am using the ruby language and I can use Regex's, also to note that I feel that my code is too complex I know I can make it much simpler please help

Comment: Are digits (numbers) to be ignored also ? I would assume yes ?

Comment: The phrase "non-word characters" may be hard to understand with a language that embrases internationalization.  Do you mean only ASCII Characters that are from a-z, A-Z?  Otherwise, rely on the regexp definition of this with their token \W

Answer (score 1):

```
def palindrome? str
  str = str.gsub(/\W/, "").downcase
  str.reverse == str
end
```

Comment: Using `\W` means that underscores are not ignored. In the question it's also unclear whether numbers should be ignored. This also doesn't ignore numbers

Comment: @KassymDorsel the OP said `nonword` and if you check the ruby api `/\W/ - A non-word character` so sounds good to me.